# Should I use controller methods from a form object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, sorcery

I'm using `Sorcery` gem.

I have a `sessions_controller` which handles login/logout. I want to extract controller-unrelated code like form validation and signing the user into a form object.

However, to login user, I need an access to the sessions_controller, as it requires access to the controller context. Obviously, I can pass controller into the form object, but I don't like tying them at all. Here's how it looks:

```
# SessionsController:
# ...
def create
  @form = SignInForm.new(session_params)
  @form.set_controller self

  if @form.valid?
    redirect_signed_in_users
  else
    render :new, status: :unauthorized
  end
end

# SignInForm
( unnecessary stuff omitted
class SignInForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :email, String
  attribute :password, String
  attribute :controller, ActionController::Base, writer: :private

  validates_presence_of :email, :password
  validate :valid_credentials

  def set_controller(controller)
    self.controller = controller
  end

  private

  def valid_credentials
    errors.add(:base) unless controller.login(self.email, self.password,      self.remember_me)
 end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldnt do it. Feels like `login` method contains validation which makes the form object ambiguous

Comment: @apneadiving Yes, it does. SignInForm also contains logic for showing errors, and handles virtual attributes (ie remember_me) that I don't want to put into user model.

Comment: its sort of a edge case there. Does the method come from a gem? Can you easily change it?

Comment: `login` method comes from Sorcery gem..oh, I just looked into its source code, and it provides User#authenticate method which returns matching user for valid credentials.. and `auto_login` method for the controller